# CORS working in development mode not in production. ExpressJS / ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

I have an ExpressJS backend server and it works on development. However when i deployed it on the production server and access it routes, it got an error about CORS.

Here is the CORS error in the front end.

```
    Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://docs-api.azurewebsites.net/login' from origin 
   'https://docs-front.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control- 
   Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Request header Production

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fil;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 110
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: https://docs-api.azurewebsites.net/login
Origin: https://docs-front.azurewebsites.net
Referer: https://docs-front.azurewebsites.net/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1.
```

Request header local

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fil;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 144
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host: localhost:3002
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_2_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.3 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
```

Server.js

```
require("dotenv").config()
var express = require("express")
var path = require("path")
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
var logger = require("morgan")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var cors = require("cors")

var db = require("./config/database")
var indexRouter = require("./routes/index")

var app = express()

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"))
app.set("view engine", "jade")

app.use(logger("dev"))
app.use(cookieParser(process.env.secretkey))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.use(
  cors({
    origin: *,
    credentials: true,
    exposedHeaders: ["Content-Length", "X-Foo", "X-Bar"],
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    allowedHeaders:
      "Origin, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
)

app.use("/", indexRouter)

db.authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`connected to Sequelize`)
    // signupModel.sync({ force: true })
    // profileModel.sync({ force: true })
    //db.sync();
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))


module.exports = app
```

front end code

```
const result = await Axios.post(`${URL_LOGIN}/login`, {
    email: values.email,
    password: values.password,
    headers: {
       "Content-type": "application/json",
    }
 })
```

It works using postman on the development mode. But on the prod it's not.

Comment: Compare development request header with production request header.

Comment: development request header sets "Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site" while production "Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site"

Answer (score 0):

As CORS configuration (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options) '*' doesn't seems to be valid value for origin, maybe you can try passing your front-end url to allow CORS.

Json

```
{
  origin: 'https://docs-front.azurewebsites.net'
}
```

or set it to true allow to reflect the request origin, as defined by docs

Json

```
{
  origin: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***You can modify allowedHeaders and methods below;***

```
const whitelist = [
  'https://docs-front.azurewebsites.net',
  'http://localhost:3000',
];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (!origin || whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('CORS ERROR'));
    }
  },
  allowedHeaders: [
    'Access-Control-Request-Method',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
    'Origin',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'Content-Type',
    'Accept',
    'Authorization',
    'X-HTTP-Method-Override',
    'Set-Cookie',
    'Cookie',
    'Request',
    'withCredentials',
  ],
  methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
  credentials: true,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  origin: [
    'https://docs-front.azurewebsites.net',
    'http://localhost:3000',
  ],
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score -1):

The cors is now working. The changes are not that updated right away. I am using Azure Web App Services.